# Trouble running MySQL REGEXP_SUBSTR within STR_TO_DATE to extract date from text

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, regexp-substr, str-to-date

I'm having trouble running MySQL REGEXP_SUBSTR within STR_TO_DATE to extract a date from a text field.

If can run the following query, and use REGEXP_SUBSTR to properly extract the date string.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('12/9/97 - Ependymoma!', '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}');
# '12/9/97'
```

If I hard code the date string in STR_TO_DATE, I can properly convert the date string to a DATE.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('12/9/97', '%m/%d/%y');
# '1997-12-09'
```

However, if I call the REGEXP_SUBSTR within STR_TO_DATE it returns NULL.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('12/9/97 - Ependymoma!', '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}'), '%m/%d/%y');
# NULL
```

I've been struggling with this. Any direction would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Not reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd4d211261efb683d718f984e3bb388f

Comment: I also tested on a local instance of MySQL 8.0 and it works. It does not return NULL. What does `SELECT VERSION();` return for you?

Comment: SELECT VERSION() -> 8.0.12, running on Mac. Thanks.

Comment: Try selecting the date into a local variable first

`SELECT @tmp := REGEXP_SUBSTR('12/9/97 - Ependymoma!', '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}')`
`SELECT STR_TO_DATE(@tmp, '%m/%d/%y')`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for all of the help! Several commenters had no problems with my code, but I could not get this to work in my recently installed version of MySQL. I have to get this work done, so I switched to PostgreSQL and had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the date into a local variable first

```
SELECT @tmp := REGEXP_SUBSTR('12/9/97 - Ependymoma!', '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}')
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(@tmp, '%m/%d/%y');
```

Also posted as an `answer` cos I couldn't get the `comment` to show two lines, so it was a mess

BTW: your original combined statement works fine for `10.4.8-MariaDB`

Comment: Thanks. I tried the local variable and that did not work. Weird. the dbfiddle from Akina also worked.

Comment: that's VERY odd, considering the two statements work separately, with constants. I wonder if it's something to do with converting character sets? What happens if you add `select @tmp` in between the two? Also, when you say `it didn't work` what happened, just `NULL` again?

Comment: Yes, by not working it just returned NULL. I've tried both the command line and within MySQL workbench and no go. Using @tmp in between did not work either. Thanks everyone for all your help! I tried the equivalent operation with PostgreSQL and had no problems.